# How can I simplify the if - else statements?

Tags: c++, function, class, oop, c++17

I finished creating a - very noob, because I'm still a noob :( - program that acts as a bank account.

I have `main.cpp`, `Account.cpp`, `Account.h`.

In `main.cpp` I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Account.h"

int main()
{   
    Account Luigis;
    Luigis.set_name("Luigi's Account");
    Luigis.set_balance(0);
    std::string letter;
   
do  {
    std::cout << "Your current balance is: " << Luigis.get_balance() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "What would you like, to deposit, to withdraw or to exit?" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "(D for 'Deposit, W for 'Withdraw' and Q for 'Exit') D/W/Q ";
    std::cin >> letter;
    if(letter == "d" || letter == "D") {
        std::cout << "How much would you like to deposit?: ";
        double amountDeposit{};
        std::cin >> amountDeposit;
        Luigis.deposit(amountDeposit);
    }
        else if(letter == "w" || letter == "W") {
            std::cout << "How much would you like to withdraw?: ";
            double amountWithdraw;
            std::cin >> amountWithdraw;
            Luigis.withdraw(amountWithdraw);
        }
            else if(letter == "q" || letter == "Q") {
                std::cout << "Goodbye!" << std::endl;
            }
                else 
                std::cout << "Invalid selection, please try again with: D for Deposit, W for Withdraw, Q for Exist" << std::endl;
                
    
    } while (letter != "q" && letter != "Q");
    
    return 0;
}
```

In `Account.cpp` I have:

```
#include "Account.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
//IMPLEMENTATION or DEFINITION

bool Account::deposit(double amount) {
    //money you're doing to deposit
    balance = balance + amount;
    }

bool Account::withdraw(double amount) {
        //if you can withdraw
        if(balance-amount >= 0) {
             balance = balance - amount;
             return true;
            } else {
                std::cout << "You cannot withdraw the specified amount - balance is too low and it would result in " << balance - amount << " funds!" << std::endl;
                return false;
                }
        }
    
void Account::set_name(std::string name) {
        this->name = name;
        }

std::string Account::get_name(){
        return name;
        }

void Account::set_balance(double balance) {
        this->balance = balance;
    }

double Account::get_balance() {
        return balance;
    }
```

And in `Account.h` I have:

```
#ifndef _ACCOUNT_H_
#define _ACCOUNT_H_
#include <string>
//SPECIFICATION or DECLARATION


class Account
{
private:
    //attributes
    std::string name;
    double balance;
public:
    //methods
    bool deposit(double amount);
    bool withdraw(double amount);
    void set_name(std::string name);
    std::string get_name();
    void set_balance(double balance);
    double get_balance();
};

#endif // _ACCOUNT_H_
```

My question is: how can I simplify the `if`-`else` statements in `main.cpp` now that I "know" how to use functions? My friend said that I should be able to use functions and make things more abstract to avoid writing all the `if` and `else` statements.

*Basically I'm mixing OOP with Procedural Programming, and that defeats the purpose.*

Comment: (1) I don't see any real problem with your if-else statements other than indentation. (2) Extracting the body of each if-else might make it more readable, and is trivial. (3) If you want to avoid the if-and else entirely, you'll want a map, but that often results in _less_ readable code. tldr; I think your code is fine (other than indentation)

Comment: you have way too much code that is completely irrelevant to your question. Please create a [MRE] (emphasis on "minimal")

Comment: If letter is always a single character you can probably use `char`, instead of `std::string` and use a switch statement

Comment: Fold the case?  `letter = toupper(letter); ... if (letter == 'Q')` or `switch (toupper(letter)) case 'Q': ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an exaggerated impression of complexity concerning your conditional constructs. To me (and at least 5 others, judging from comments and the "agrees" the got) they do not seem overly complex.

I hence propose something to change your impression, though it will not change the functionality at all:
Please apply consistent and strict indentation, the actual style is irrelevant.
If you allow me to propose my favorite style, here is an example of the result:

```
if(letter == "d" || letter == "D")
{
    std::cout << "How much would you like to deposit?: ";
    double amountDeposit{};
    std::cin >> amountDeposit;
    Luigis.deposit(amountDeposit);
} else if(letter == "w" || letter == "W")
{
    std::cout << "How much would you like to withdraw?: ";
    double amountWithdraw;
    std::cin >> amountWithdraw;
    Luigis.withdraw(amountWithdraw);
} else if(letter == "q" || letter == "Q")
{
    std::cout << "Goodbye!" << std::endl;
} else 
{
    std::cout << "Invalid selection, please try again with: D for Deposit, W for Withdraw, Q for Exist"
              << std::endl;
}
```